# Announcer, Booster, Publicist Badges -- How exactly are these earned?

Tags: support

How exactly is a link to whatever question tracked back to your username? I assumed some sort of link with a username in it or some kind of key, but I couldn't find that anywhere.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is the connection between the question title and the body?

Comment: Hey John, it seems pretty clear to me, if there is something misleading I'd be glad to edit if youd be so kind as to point out exactly what you think doesn't fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that "link" link under the question? Click that. Or copy the URL it links to. That link in turn links to your profile so anyone following that link to this question (such as one sent to Slashdot) will credit you with a view.

Comment: Wow. That's almost an embarrassing oversight. Thank you. That said, I also lost my keys in the fridge once, but that's another story.

Comment: @serverninja: fwiw, SF question URLs are of the format "serverfault.com" / "q" / *question number*.  The "crediting" URL is just the question URL with your user ID number tacked on the end. *e.g.* This question: `meta.serverfault.com/q/944` -- Credit URL using your user ID: `meta.serverfault.com/q/944/23935`